# Fade from page to page with loading bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, fadein, fade

I'm seeing this sort of effect a lot lately - and I like it!

Although it seems like an easy thing to search for, I can't find anything that gives me the answer I'm looking for. I'm sure someone can correct me on that though.

Basically I'm after a simple effect where once a (internal) nav/page link is clicked, the page will fadeout and back in to the page the user's been directed to.

I can find *some* stuff on this but the additional bit I'd like is for there to be a loading bar at the top of the browser that grows along the top of the page until the new page is ready.

I've found a few examples of the effect:

1. https://grainandmortar.com
2. http://www.hochburg.net/de

The first is probably the more simple, graceful effect I'm after.

Hope someone can help with this. Every example/tutorial I find seems to be a bit over complicated or have crazy effects added to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an Animation template. You cand find here http://git.blivesta.com/animsition/ a "Demo" and a "Download link.

Comment: That looks pretty good. I found some stuff like that previously but I always moved on as it didn't have the loading bar with it. I'm not sure that can be manipulated to do something similar?

Comment: Of course you can just fake that loading bar. Just use those examples form w3schools. Link: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_progressbar.asp

Comment: Wouldn't that just increase the width regardless of the loading time? Just thinking so it doesn't reach 100% and then the page is still loading?

Comment: But that's what you want or not? This is just a simple width that gets incrased by 100%. If your looking for something more professional. Go check this 2 links out.
Link0: http://github.hubspot.com/pace/
Link1: http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/
Have fun <3

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i'm in the wrong way,

On link click event, attach a javascript function that will use prevent default function , that will stop the redirect process, fadeout your body element and then trigger the window.location manually.

By default add a opacity 0  for each page and attach an event on the body tag "on content loaded  you will manually set your opacity to 1 with a funky function as fadin.

This is only the principle get back to me if your are interested in real javascript code

Good luck

Comment: Hey, that sounds interesting. I don't know a lot about it if I'm honest, it's why I thought I'd post something here. I'm really not sure what 'best practice' would be here ...but I suppose there probably isn't one! Best practice would probably be 'don't do it' haha! But sometimes when you're trying to show off/come up with nice effects it's ok I think.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd update this with my solution incase in comes in handy for anyone else.

I decided to use the pace.js plugin which is very useful for loading bars. It also adds a class to the body element of `.pace-done` once the page has loaded. Pace automatically adds a couple of divs to the top of your page which you can style as your progress bar.

So basically I set a value of `opacity: 0;` on my content which is wrapped in a `.page` div. Until the page is loaded when I set `opacity: 1;` with a transition to fade in the content. There's also a fallback where if javascript is not loaded we overwrite the styling so the content is always visible and never opaque.

Here's the the css, I'll include my pace.js loading bar styling as well:

```
/**
 * When pace.js is running we add `opacity` to the `body` element so we can fade
 * the page in with a transition once it's loaded.
 */

.page {
    opacity: 0;

    .pace-done & {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: opacity .5s ease;
    }

    .no-js & {
        opacity: 1 !important;
    }
}


/**
 * Progress bar styles.
 */

.pace {
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.pace-inactive {
  display: none;
}

.pace .pace-progress {
    background: $color-primary;
    height: 4px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2000;  
}
```

All in all this is a nice little effect and works really well. It's not massively important but I thought I'd fade the page out slightly before it's redirected but I needed to use javascript for this. Here's the code I used:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //$('body').css('display', 'none');
    //$('body').fadeIn(200);

    $('a:not(.page-head__toggle)').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        newLocation = this.href;
        $('body').fadeOut(150, newpage);
    });

    function newpage() {
        window.location = newLocation;
    }
});
```

Not this does target every link on the page except my navigation menu toggle. So maybe not great if you have 1000's of links. You could always specify a class and only target links with that class added.

Hope this helps someone else! :)